# python - pass values from list to url "GET" request

Tags: python, python-requests, get-request

I'm trying to write a code which takes a list of Extension IDs, then passes each ID to google, in order to perform a simple GET request.
Example url: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/(IDGoesHere)

I've searched the requests library documentation, google and also here, but all I found were ways of passing parameters to the request itself, but not to the URL.

When running the below code, python is either stuck or gives out the dreaded "syntax error" message:

```
import csv
import requests
with open('extensions.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        extids = row[0]
    for id in extids:
        r = requests.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[id]")
    print r
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

`r = requests.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[id]")`

should be:

`r = requests.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/{}".format(id))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) built-in to format your URL:

```
import csv
import requests
with open('extensions.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        extids = row[0]
    for id in extids:
        r = requests.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/{}".format(id))
print r
```